# Is it gas efficient to call another contract's external function in a loop?

Tags: gas, security, staking, external-function

I am trying to create a staking protocols where rewards and staking are separate. But there are multiple tokens that get rewarded and I need to update each of them in a loop. Now, my question is how good of a practice is it to call function for calculation of rewards in the reward contract for each token in a loop from a staking contract.

I have seen few contracts that actually does this but is it gas efficient and secure. I want to modularize the contract as much as possible.

Comment: can you sharethe contract?

Comment: https://github.com/aurora-is-near/aurora-staking-contracts/blob/main/contracts/JetStakingV1.sol